# Difference between content_type=application/json and format=json in DRF APIClient

Tags: json, django, django-rest-framework

I'm using `rest_framework.test.APIClient` for unit tests in my project. I used a dictionary as a request data, so `None` values there are not parsed properly as it doesn't understand the format. I added `format="json"` as a parameter to `client.post()` and it worked fine. However adding `content_type="application/json"` solved the problem as well and I want to know what's the difference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `APIClient` in rest framework extends from the test client in django app and adds extra functionalities using `APIRequestFactory` to deal with each type of request e.g. get, post etc. The django test client accepts `content_type` and the rest framework APIClient accepts both `format` and `content_type`. But, you can't set both at the same time in the `APIClient` as it will throw an error.

Let's look at both the scenarios:

- **Using `content_type='application/json'`**:

  In this case, the `content_type` is passed as it is to the django test client and there it uses `json` module to dump the data if the data is one of `dict`, `list` or `tuple`.
- **Using `format=json`**:

  rest_framework has a setting `TEST_REQUEST_RENDERER_CLASSES` where it defines different renderers for different types of data.

  ```
  'TEST_REQUEST_RENDERER_CLASSES': [
      'rest_framework.renderers.MultiPartRenderer',
      'rest_framework.renderers.JSONRenderer'
  ],
  ```

  From these renderers, `APIRequestFactory` creates a mapping between the specified format as the key. When `format='json'` is sent in the request, it looks for the renderer and matches `JSONRenderer`. It then tries to encode the given data using this particular renderer. This renderer also specifies the `media_type` which equals to `application/json` and is set as `content_type` and both the encoded data and `content_type` are passed to django test client. Because now the encoded data is a string, even passing `content_type` won't dump the data twice.

Comment: Wow, great answer. Now I know the reason why some nested data isn't parsed properly when passing `format='json'`